# Why is Deque (ArrayDeque) capacity a power of two?

Tags: java, deque, capacity, arraydeque

In Java (but similarly in PHP) the `ArrayDeque` implementation always has its capacity as a power of 2:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayDeque.java#l126

For `HashMap` this choice is clear - to have a uniform element distribution based on a trimmed 32-bit hash. But `Deque` inserts/removes elements sequentially.

Also, `ArrayList` doesn't restrict its capacity to a power of two, just ensures it's at least the number of elements.

So, **why does the `Deque` implementation require its capacity to be a power of 2**?

Comment: The reason HashMap keeps its capacity a power of 2 is not because of element distribution; it's for exactly the same reason ArrayDeque does: `&` is faster than `%`.

Comment: Then why other collections (like ArrayList) don't use this way for faster operations?

Comment: Hey, can we somehow ping Josh Bloch or Doug Lea as they seems to be the authors of the implementation?
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayDeque.java#l81

Comment: Because ArrayList doesn't have a use for `&` or `%`. Hash tables and deques do.

Answer (score 6):

I guess, for performance reasons. For example, let's look at implementation of `addLast` function:

```
public void addLast(E e) {
    if (e == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    elements[tail] = e;
    if ( (tail = (tail + 1) & (elements.length - 1)) == head)
        doubleCapacity();
}
```

So, instead of `tail = (tail + 1) % elements.length` it is possible to write `tail = (tail + 1) & (elements.length - 1)` (`&` works faster, than `%`). Such constructions are used many times in `ArrayDeque`'s source code.

Comment: You're partially correct. But I like WJS's answer better. The bottom line is that "powers of two" has many advantages, for multiple different reasons. It a) simplifies setting initial size, b) simplifies resizing ("just double it"), c) simplifies deletes, etc.  And yes, it also allows the use of binary operations that allow for some low-level performance gains :)  I didn't list it in my response, but look at the deque's [next()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayDeque.java#l688) method for a good example of what WJS is talking about.

Comment: @leo-leonter what do you think about this reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56790744/907576 ?

Answer (score 4):

Finally i found it!!! 
The reason not just in performance and bits-mask operations (yes, they are faster, but not significantly). The real reason is to **allow *loop back* the `elements` capacity if we use sequential adding-removing operations**. In other words: reuse released cells after `remove()` operation.

Consider the following examples (initial capacity is **16**):

1. **Only `add()`**:

   1. add 15 elements => head=0, tail=15
   2. add more 5 elements => **`doubleCapacity()`** => head=0, tail=20, capacity=32

   [image]
2. **`add()`-`remove()`-`add()`**:

   1. add 15 elements => head=0, tail=15
   2. **remove** 10 elements => tail *loops back* to removed indexes => head=10, tail=15
   3. add more 5 elements => the capacity remains 16, the `elements[]` array is not rebuilt or reallocated! => new elements are added into the place of the removed elements to the beginning of the array => head=10, tail=4 (**looped back** to the start of the array from 15->0->1->2->3->4). Note the values 16-19 are inserted to the indexes 0-3

   [image]

So, in this case using power of two and concise bit operations makes much more sense. With such approach the operations like `if ( (tail = (tail + 1) & (elements.length - 1)) == head)` allow to assign and verify easily that the *looped* `tail` does not overlap with the `head` (yeah, the stupid snake where actually the tail bites the head :) )

The code snippet to play around:

```
ArrayDeque<String> q = new ArrayDeque<>(15); // capacity is 16

// add 15 elements
q.add("0"); q.add("1"); q.add("2"); q.add("3"); q.add("4");
q.add("5"); q.add("6"); q.add("7"); q.add("8"); q.add("9");
q.add("10"); q.add("11");q.add("12");q.add("13");q.add("14");

// remove 10 elements from the head => tail LOOPS BACK in the elements[]
q.poll();q.poll();q.poll();q.poll();q.poll();q.poll();q.poll();q.poll();q.poll();q.poll();

// add 5 elements => the elements[] is not reallocated!
q.add("15");q.add("16");q.add("17");q.add("18");q.add("19");


q.poll();
```

Comment: The "Duroboros Effect" ;)  That's what I tried to say above ("...the deque is never allowed to reach capacity").  Glad you figured it out.  And glad you realized that "micro optimizations" using binary operators was *NOT* the primary motivation :)

Answer (score 2):

Powers of 2 lend themselves to certain masking operations.  For example to get the lower order number of bits from an integer.

so if the size is 64, then 64-1 is 63 which is 111111 in binary.

This facilitates locating or placing elements within the deque.

Comment: Excellent response :) The [next()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayDeque.java#l688) method in the deque code is a good example of what you mean by "facilitates locating or placing elements within the deque".  Note the "cursor".

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

Looking in the code:

1. As you said, the capacity is always a power of two.  Furthermore, the deque is never allowed to *reach* capacity.

   ```
   public class ArrayDeque<E> extends AbstractCollection<E>
                              implements Deque<E>, Cloneable, Serializable
   {
       /**
        * The array in which the elements of the deque are stored.
        * The capacity of the deque is the length of this array, which is
        * always a power of two. The array is never allowed to become
        * full, except transiently within an addX method where it is
        * resized (see doubleCapacity) immediately upon becoming full,
        * thus avoiding head and tail wrapping around to equal each
        * other....
   ```
2. The "power of two" convention simplifies "initial size":

   ```
    /**
     * Allocates empty array to hold the given number of elements.
     *
     * @param numElements  the number of elements to hold
     */
    private void allocateElements(int numElements) {
        int initialCapacity = MIN_INITIAL_CAPACITY;
        // Find the best power of two to hold elements.
        // Tests "<=" because arrays aren't kept full.
        if (numElements >= initialCapacity) {
            initialCapacity = numElements;
            initialCapacity |= (initialCapacity >>>  1);
            initialCapacity |= (initialCapacity >>>  2);
            initialCapacity |= (initialCapacity >>>  4);
            initialCapacity |= (initialCapacity >>>  8);
            initialCapacity |= (initialCapacity >>> 16);
            initialCapacity++;

            if (initialCapacity < 0)   // Too many elements, must back off
                initialCapacity >>>= 1;// Good luck allocating 2 ^ 30 elements
        }
   ```
3. Finally, note the use of "mask":

   ```
    /**
     * Removes the last occurrence of the specified element in this
     * deque (when traversing the deque from head to tail).
     * If the deque does not contain the element, it is unchanged.
     * More formally, removes the last element {@code e} such that
     * {@code o.equals(e)} (if such an element exists).
     * Returns {@code true} if this deque contained the specified element
     * (or equivalently, if this deque changed as a result of the call).
     *
     * @param o element to be removed from this deque, if present
     * @return {@code true} if the deque contained the specified element
     */
    public boolean removeLastOccurrence(Object o) {
        if (o == null)
            return false;
        int mask = elements.length - 1;
        int i = (tail - 1) & mask;
        Object x;
        while ( (x = elements[i]) != null) {
            if (o.equals(x)) {
                delete(i);
                return true;
            }
            i = (i - 1) & mask;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean delete(int i) {
        checkInvariants();
        ...
        // Invariant: head <= i < tail mod circularity
        if (front >= ((t - h) & mask))
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        ...
        // Optimize for least element motion
        if (front < back) {
            if (h <= i) {
                System.arraycopy(elements, h, elements, h + 1, front);
            } else { // Wrap around
                System.arraycopy(elements, 0, elements, 1, i);
                elements[0] = elements[mask];
                System.arraycopy(elements, h, elements, h + 1, mask - h);
            }
            elements[h] = null;
            head = (h + 1) & mask;
   ```

Comment: what do you thin about this explanation?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56790744/907576

i found it when i debugged the implementation